# How do I make every canvas object "clickable"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I figured how to detect a mouseclick in `canvas`. Now I need to solve these 2 things:

1. Is it posible to call the functions containing the specific drawings in an array? That's because drawn areas are divided in a different functions, therefore, I want to just "import" such functions.
2. How do I "link" an object's location with its information?

Here's the code to make `rect()` "clickable":

```
function clickBooth() {
  elemLeft = canvas.offsetLeft,
  elemTop = canvas.offsetTop,
  context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  elements = [];
  var boothTF = drawBoothGroup35;

// Add event listener for `click` events.
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var x = event.pageX - elemLeft,
      y = event.pageY - elemTop;
  console.log(x, y);
  elements.forEach(function(element) {
      if (y > element.top && y < element.top + element.height && x > 
  element.left && x < element.left + element.width) {
          alert('clicked an element');
      }
  });

}, false);

// Add element. Can I just add the functions here??
elements.push({
   colour: '#05EFFF',
   width: 150,
   height: 100,
   top: 20,
   left: 15
   }
);

// Render elements.
elements.forEach(function(element) {
   context.fillStyle = element.colour;
   context.fillRect(element.left, element.top, element.width, element.height);
   });
   }
console.log(clickBooth);
```

---

I'm trying to achieve the following interaction:
**Click green box** (booth) > **???** (this is where I'm lost) > **Display green box** (booth) **information in an iFram**e (red rectangle far right)

[image]

This is a live sample of what I have achieved: https://codepen.io/izwicky/pen/xzKWYX

Comment: I read your question multiple times and wasnt able to understand it. Can you maybe rephrase it?

Comment: Sorry for that, I've blown many brain fuses... So I already have a `canvas` with objects in it (rectangles). I want to know how do I track mouse 'onclick' for every single object and display information depending on which object was clicked. Maybe I should update main question??

Comment: This is much clearer. Please update the question. However, your function already checks WHICH element was clicked. So I dont see your issue.

Comment: Yes, it detects which element was clicked but, in the live example you will see it's behaviour... Only the "test" object is clickable but not the others.

Comment: You never add the "booth" shape to your `elements` array. Therefore the handler loops over an array which holds only ONE element (the one which is clickable). You need to add all the other elements as well!

Comment: Canvas might not be the right tool for what you're trying to do; this would be a lot easier using regular DOM elements.  Objects drawn into a canvas aren't objects anymore, they're just pixels, so the only way to detect which one the user clicked on is to separately keep track of their bounding rects and check if the click was within one of them, as you're doing. (Or you can draw each element in a slightly different color, and use the color at the clicked point to identify the correct element -- but this only works for flat, uniformly-colored objects.)

Comment: @DanielBeck It feels like this side project is time consuming...probably because of my tool choice. Specifically, wha'ts your recommendation? Should I use a framework? Other language?

Comment: Without a *lot* more detail about what you're doing, there's no way to recommend a specific framework (and it's largely a matter of opinion anyway.) But based on what you've shown above, each of your green rectangles could just be a `<div>` or other DOM element with a click event attached to bring up the extra information in the red rectangle; then the browser will do the work of positioning and keeping track of which element was clicked.

Comment: @DanielBeck That sounds waayy better as I will avoid many headaches. What worries me is if I'll be able to zoom-in/out and drag the DOM elements as if they were a single image...maybe with JS? Which I could talk to you more about this, I really liked how you pointed this new direction.